# Como fazer um layout de colunas responsivo com js?

Tags: javascript, html, layout-responsivo

Eu preciso criar um layout de colunas (masonry) responsivo com js puro. Já tentei de várias maneiras, mas a maioria das colunas não são responsivas, e o CSS organiza a numeração de cima para baixo.

[image: Um exemplo do que eu quero fazer]

A responsividade seria:

- **Em celulares:** ter uma coluna horizontalmente.
- **Em tablets:** ter duas colunas horizontalmente.
- **Em computadores:** ter três colunas horizontalmente.

Estou usando esse código, mas não consigo deixar o layout responsivo ou mudar as larguras sem destruir o layout.

```js
function renderGrid() {
    var blocks = document.getElementById("grid_container").children;
    var pad = 10,
        cols = 3,
        newleft, newtop;
    for (var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        if (i % cols == 0) {
            newtop = (blocks[i - cols].offsetTop + blocks[i - cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.top = newtop + "px";
        } else {
            if (blocks[i - cols]) {
                newtop = (blocks[i - cols].offsetTop + blocks[i - cols].offsetHeight) + pad;
                blocks[i].style.top = newtop + "px";
            }
            newleft = (blocks[i - 1].offsetLeft + blocks[i - 1].offsetWidth) + pad;
            blocks[i].style.left = newleft + "px";
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderGrid, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", renderGrid, false);
```

```css
div#grid_container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 860px;
    border: #999 1px dashed;
}
div#grid_container > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 291px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}
div#grid_container > div:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background: #FFDC64;
}
div#grid_container > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #FEC910;
}
div#grid_container > div > div {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: #D9A800;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 
<body>
<div id="grid_container">
  <div style="height:140px;"> <div>1</div> </div>
  <div style="height:200px;"> <div>2</div> </div>
  <div style="height:120px;"> <div>3</div> </div>
  <div style="height:180px;"> <div>4</div> </div>
  <div style="height:150px;"> <div>5</div> </div>
  <div style="height:160px;"> <div>6</div> </div>
  <div style="height:180px;"> <div>7</div> </div>
  <div style="height:170px;"> <div>8</div> </div>
  <div style="height:160px;"> <div>9</div> </div>
  <div style="height:180px;"> <div>10</div> </div>
  <div style="height:150px;"> <div>11</div> </div>
  <div style="height:160px;"> <div>12</div> </div>
  <div style="height:130px;"> <div>13</div> </div>
  <div style="height:140px;"> <div>14</div> </div>
  <div style="height:210px;"> <div>15</div> </div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: @Phanpy vou editar para ficar mais claro!

Comment: @Phanpy Mas a minha grande dúvida é como fazer o código para ficar nesse layout!

Comment: Algo impede você de usar [um **plugin**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)? É chatão ter que fazer isso do zero, se for para estudos acho que até vale a pena.

Comment: @Renan É para os dois, não gosto de usar plugins e também é para estudo!

Comment: Flexbox vai te ajudar bastante, de uma olhada.

Comment: @Phanpy eu quero por porcentagem, mas o código que consegui é estático!

Comment: @Phanpy Coloquei

Comment: @BrunoWego vou procurar sobre o assunto!

Comment: Acabei criando um [rascunho](https://jsfiddle.net/bqLj7nwp/4/) antes do edit. Estou tentando fazer funcionar ainda. Esqueci totalmente sobre HTML e CSS :/

Comment: @Phanpy já eu sou um iniciante no js, vi esse código que você fez e entendi pouco.

Comment: Te aconselho a usar apenas CSS para fazer isso, eu uso essa topico como base: https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.bb64irsui

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar bootstrap para resolver responsividades, faz de maneira automática para você.

Answer (score -1):

Você consegue fazer isso apenas com CSS:

```
.grid_container{
  width: 100%;
  column-count: 4;
}

.child{
  display:block;
  min-height: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/bqb3a3hk/

Comment: Um problema, se o tamanho da janela é pequeno (ou de celular) deveria ser mostrada apenas uma coluna por linha, como na questão, e em tablets seriam 2 colunas por linha.

Comment: Eu já tentei, mas a ordem não fica correta, o que deveria estar nas primeiras linhas horizontais por exemplo, vai para o final da pagina! Eu preciso de algo como está na imagem que eu mandei, pois será uma galeria dinâmica!

Comment: Ta vendo ali aquela propriedade `column-count` ?  Você consegue controlar a quantidade de colunascom ela, então, use as media queries do CSS para controlar a quantidade de colunas de acordo a resolução dos aparelho.

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid_container{
     column-count: 2;
   }
}`